# orientdb: why so slow to get connected nodes?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to get all the connected nodes to a particular node via a specific edge type with some required edge attributes. Why does this query take so long (~10 minutes)?

```
SELECT inV().@rid as rid, inV().thing1.code as code1, 
inV().thing2.code as code2 FROM ( 
   SELECT EXPAND(outE("NamedRelationship")) FROM [#9:6512] 
   WHERE NOT (relationship_attribute IN ["A", "B", "C"]) 
)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on "relationship_attribute"?  If you've got a big table you could start there and see how fast things run.

Comment: @stdunbar never mind, I do already have an index on this attribute. Still the operation is quite slow.

Comment: @stdunbar would any other indices help, or another way of writing this query?